# All polynomials of order $p$ can be written as $\sum a_i (1 + t_i x)^p$?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, polynomials

Given a bivariate function (called "kernel")

$$K(t,x) = (1 + tx)^p, t\in\mathbb{R}, x\in\mathbb{R}$$

I am looking at the space $H$ consists of

$$f(x) = \sum_{i=1}^n a_i (1 + t_i x)^p$$

It's obvious that the space $H$ is in the space of polynomials of order $p$, but how do I show the converse? Namely, is it true that for any polynomial of order $p$, there exists $a_1,\cdots, a_n$ and $t_1, \cdots, t_n$ such that

$$k_p x^p + \cdots + k_1 x + k_0 = \sum_{i=1}^n a_i \left(1 + t_i x\right)^p?$$

I tried to expand the right hand side and I don't think that helps.

Comment: Is this over a field?  What is it's characteristic?

Comment: @Qudit Everything is in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Hint: Vandermonde.

Comment: Taking derivative of order $m=0,1,...,p$ and evaluating at $x=0$ we get 

$$\frac{k_m}{\binom{p}{m}}=\sum a_it_i^m$$

Therefore, if we choose the $t_1,...,t_{p+1}$ to be different, then there is a unique solution for the $a_i$ satisfying this system of $p+1$ equations.

Comment: @ZachTeitler Aha I think I know it now. Actually did some homework on Vandermonde matrix years ago but never saw it again...

Comment: What's the relationship between $n$ and $p$? In particular does $n=p+1$?

Comment: @user7530 $n$ is something that we choose in advance. We can actually choose it to be the same as $p$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Vandermonde determinant shows that for any $p+1$ distinct $t_i$, $(1+t_i x)^p$ are linearly independent, hence span the polynomials of degree $\leq p$. (This is equivalent to the comment by @Hellen.) To give a tiny bit of detail: For fixed $t_1,\dotsc,t_{p+1}$, the matrix whose entries are the coefficients of the $(1+t_i x)^p$, along rows say, is a slightly modified Vandermonde matrix: each entry is a $t_i^j$, times a binomial coefficient. The binomial factors are constant on each column. This affects the determinant of the matrix, but it doesn't change that the matrix still has full rank.

So, every polynomial $f$ can be written as a combination of $p+1$ of the $(1+tx)^p$'s (in fact, using *any* $p+1$ of them). By a very general result, for any $f$, there exist *some* $t_1,\dotsc,t_p$ ($n=p$ instead of $p+1$) s.t. the span of the $(1+t_i x)^p$ includes $f$: in a nutshell, a general hyperplane through $f$ cuts the curve $\{(1+tx)^p \mid t \in \mathbb{R}\}$ in $p$ points because that's the curve's degree; those points span the hyperplane, including $f$.

Certainly many $f$ require fewer than $p$ terms. (E.g., $f=(1+t_1 x)^p + (1+t_2 x)^p$ requires just $2$.) Examples like $f=x$ show (non-obviously) that $n=p$ can be required.

Further study of this, from an algebraic/geometric point of view is often referred to by terms like *Waring rank* and *symmetric rank of symmetric tensors*. If you're interested, some nice introductions include [Reznick, *On the length of binary forms*, 2010](https://arxiv.org/abs/1007.5485) (over $\mathbb{C}$ and various subfields of $\mathbb{C}$), [Reznick, *Laws of inertia in higher degree binary forms*, 2009](https://arxiv.org/abs/0906.5559) (over $\mathbb{R}$), and [Carlini, et al, *Four lectures on secant varieties*, 2013](https://arxiv.org/abs/1309.4145). (There are certainly other points of view such as interpolation/sampling, but I don't know that terminology or literature, sorry.)